# Editing Vector points in Photoshop CS4

Tags: vector-graphics

I'm kinda new in using photoshop. I'm familiar with Ai and other graphic creation software but the same principles aren't used in Ps.

Its kinda basic what Im asking. How do I edit vector points?

I can't seem to find a way to do it properly, help, please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop uses various **pen** tools to create vector **paths** which you can use to apply **stroke** and/or **fill** *as pixels* on the current layer.

Go to Photoshop CS4's help and check out the **Drawing** section for a full description.